# Can you have sub-properties in mixpanel?

Tags: javascript, mixpanel

We have objects, and we want to send information about each object to mixpanel. Like:

Contracts
-Number of Steps assigned to contract
-Number of Definitions assigned to contract

So, this is set up like:
`window.mixpanel.track('My Event', {ContractStats: {TotalSteps: 2, TotalDefinitions: 1}, TaskStats: {TotalSteps: 2, TotalDefinitions: 1}});`

But what ends up happening on the mixpanel side is I get:
`ContractStats: {'TotalSteps':2,'TotalDefinitions':1}`
and
`TaskStats: {'TotalSteps':2, 'TotalDefinitions':1}`

When what I am after is some kind of structure that has TotalSteps and TotalDefinitions as kind of child properties to ContractStats/TaskStats. Not some string version of the object I passed in. I am not sure if such a thing is possible, but it would be great if it were.

I could just add new properties for each one of these, but it would be nice to organize them in this kind of parent/child property structure just to keep related stats together. But the main goal is to be able to filter by TotalSteps and TotalDefinitions.